# Which of the sets are well ordered? Which ones are isomorphic?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, order-theory

I'm new to StackExchange and I'd like to ask you for help. 
I have been trying to solve this exercise:

$$A = \left\{3 - \frac{1}{2n} : n \in \mathbb{N} - \left\{ 0 \right\} \right\}$$
$$ B = \left\{ \pi - \frac{2}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N} - \left\{0 \right\} \right\} \cup \left\{4 \right\} $$
$$C = \left\{ 0 \right\} \cup \left\{ \frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N} - \left\{ 0 \right\} \right\} \cup \left\{2 - \frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N} - \left\{ 0 \right\} \right\}$$
Which of sets $A, B, C, \mathbb{N}, \mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{Q} - \left\{ 0 \right\}, \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R} - \left\{ 0 \right\}$ are well ordered by $\le$? Which ones are isomorphic?

I'd love to see a detailed solution to this, as I have some problems with the Set Theory subject. I'm a first year CS student.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Math Stack Exchange! What are your thoughts on this problem so far?

Comment: @EliRose Well, honestly, I have no idea how to prove that a set is well ordered. I know the definition, but that's it. 
I think that $A, B, \mathbb{N}$ are well ordered and the rest is not (I don't know how to show that they're not, too).

Comment: Well it should be clear that all the sets are totally ordered (since they're all subsets of $\mathbb{R}$), and the only other condition to be well-ordered is that every non-empty subset has a minimal element.  So for instance, can you construct an infinite decreasing sequence of elements of A?  If so, then it's not well-ordered.

Comment: @DanSimon But how to prove that such sequence doesn't exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A set is well ordered by $\leq$ if it is totally ordered by $\leq$ (there is no pair of incomparable elements) and in every non-empty subset of that set there exists a $\leq$-least element.

All of the sets in your question are totally ordered since they are all subsets of real numbers (and the relation $\leq$ is a total ordering for that set).

With this in mind, here's how you could approach the problem of well orderedness for the first three sets in your question:

- Set $A$ is well ordered: for any subset generated by the positive natural numbers $n_1 < n_2 < \dots$ the least element is equal to $3 - \frac{1}{2n_1}$.
- Set $B$ is well ordered for similar reasons.
- Set $C$ is *not* well ordered. It is the union of three sets: the second set has no least element. We can generate positive numbers arbitrarily close to $0$ by choosing larger and larger values of $n$.

For the question of which are isomorphic, look first at the cardinality of each set. A countable set such as $\mathbb{N}$ cannot be isomorphic to an uncountable set such as $\mathbb{R}$. Also look at which are well ordered and which are not. A well ordered set such as $\mathbb{N}$ is not isomorphic to, say, $\mathbb{Z}$ (one has a least element, the other does not). Thirdly note that $B$, while countable and well-ordered, has a *greatest* element (but do other sets such as $A$ and $\mathbb{N}$ do not).

Comment: Thank you very much! It's helped me a lot. 
Now I'm trying to prove that A and B are isomorphic. How to construct a bijection that will prove that?

Comment: Glad it helped! $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic in the sense that there's a bijection between them, but they aren't order isomorphic. $A$ has [order type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_type) $\omega + 1$ while $B$ has order type $\omega + 2$. I'm not sure which definition of isomorphism you're using (my answer assumed order isomorphism). Let me know if you'd like any more detail.

Comment: I'm using this definition: 
$A$ and $B$ are isomorphic if there is a bijection $f : A \rightarrow B$ and $a \le a' \Leftrightarrow f(a) \le f(a')$ for every $a,a' \in A$.
I've just started to think that there must be no such bijection because 4 is an element of B.

Comment: Yes that's correct - they are not isomorphic to each other (and neither is isomorphic to any of the other sets either).

Comment: You have written that both A and B have greatest elements. That is not true for A, is it?

Comment: Apologies - I looked read the definition of the sets incorrectly as I was writing that. $A$ has order type $\omega$ like $\mathbb{N}$ (so they are isomorphic) - they have no greatest element. I'll correct that part of the answer.

Comment: That's ok. :) I wonder if $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ are order isomorphic, though. I know there's a bijection between them, but that's all. Could you give me another hint?

Comment: One way to look at it is that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense - between every two elements there's another element. On the other hand $\mathbb{Z}$ is not densely ordered. There's no way to rearrange the set of integers, preserving order, so that it has this property.